# What is the chronological order to watch Mortal Kombat: Legacy season 1?

Tags: chronology, mortal-kombat-legacy

[Mortal Kombat: Legacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat:_Legacy) season 1, looks more character oriented and doesn't seems to be in chronological order. But Kano's appearance makes it more inconsistent if we go episode number wise. So what is the right chronological order of for Mortal Kombat: Legacy season 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After watching it again and researching a lot, I will say the answer is

It's better to go by release order.

Only chronological error in release order is Kano's appearance which suggest S01E09 aka "Cyrax & Sektor" take place before S01E01 Jax, Sonya & Kano - Part 1

> because Kano have his eyes intact in S01E09 but he lost one in S01E02.